# Google Apps: HTTP 301 to another domain?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, google-apps

I bought a domain thought Google Apps, and set up the mail service on it.  My DNS A records currently point to a non-existent Google Site (I don't like Google Sites).  How do I `HTTP 301` redirect to another domain? Do I have to separately buy hosting space on a site like `nearlyfreespeech.net`, change my DNS records, and upload a `.htaccess`, or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: `Do I have to separately buy hosting space on a site like nearlyfreespeech.net, change my DNS records...` I guess so. There is no need to redirect if you change the DNS records. You couldn't anyway, unless you have another host to redirect to and the .htaccess file is in the root of the original site, which is not possible because it does not exist as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to separately buy hosting space.  There is no other way.